# Deploying jPOS in jboss or Start jPOS Q2 in jboss

Tags: jpos

Deploying jPOS in jboss or Start jPOS Q2 in jboss. That is start jPOS server as an Internal feature of jboss application server (now wildfly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step by Step Process to start jpos Q2 in jboss**

Create a .sar file named q2mbean-1.0.sar to start the Queue.

Place the created .sar file in the .ear file (jposQ.ear).

Thus the path now is jposQ.ear/Q2mbean-1.0.sar.

Place the .ear file in the deploy directory of jboss.

***SAR CREATION:***

The Created .sar file should contain the class file named Q2Service.class 
Thus the Q2Service.class file should be in the directory given below q2mbean-1.0.sar\org\jpos\mbean.
The Q2Service.java is

> ```
> > package org.jpos.mbean;
> > 
> > import javax.management.*; import org.jboss.logging.Logger; import
> > org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport; import org.jpos.q2.Q2;
> > 
> > // Referenced classes of package org.jpos.mbean: //           
> > Q2ServiceMBean
> > 
> > public class Q2Service extends ServiceMBeanSupport implements
> > Q2ServiceMBean, Runnable {
> > 
> >     public Q2Service()
> >     {
> >         q2Server = null;
> >     }
> > 
> >     protected void startService()
> >     throws Exception
> >     {
> >         super.startService();
> >         super.log.info("Q2Service starting");
> >         String deployPath[] = {
> >                 "-d", "q2/deploy"
> >         };
> >         q2Server = new Q2(deployPath);
> >         (new Thread(this)).start();
> >     }
> > 
> >     public void run()
> >     {
> >         try
> >         {
> >             q2Server.start();
> >         }
> >         catch(MalformedObjectNameException e) { e.printStackTrace();  }
> >         catch(InstanceAlreadyExistsException e) { e.printStackTrace();  }
> >         catch(NotCompliantMBeanException e) {  e.printStackTrace();  }
> >         catch(MBeanRegistrationException e) {  e.printStackTrace(); } 
> >      }
> >     protected void stopService()
> >     throws Exception
> >     {
> >         super.stopService();
> >         super.log.info("Q2Service stopping");
> >         q2Server.shutdown();
> >     }
> >     private Q2 q2Server; }
> ```

The .sar file also have an interface named Q2ServiceMBean.class.
Q2ServiceMBean.java is

```
package org.jpos.mbean;

import org.jboss.system.ServiceMBean;

public interface Q2ServiceMBean extends ServiceMBean
{

}
```

The xml file named (jboss-service.xml) should be created in the directory q2mbean-1.0.sar\META-INF\ jboss-service.xml.

The xml says the class path to the sar :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<service>

<mbean code="org.jpos.mbean.Q2Service" name="Q2:name=Q2Service">

</mbean>

</service>
```

EAR CREATION:

Your Ear should begin with an xml file named application.xml  which should be in jposQ.ear\META-INF\application.xml

In the same way another xml file should be created which is jboss-app.xml in the jposQ.ear\META-INF\jboss-app.xml

application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd" version="1.4"> 

<display-name>JBossAtWorkEAR</display-name> 


       <module>   

          <java>jpos.jar</java>

</module>
</application>
```

jboss-app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<jboss-app>

<loader-repository>myapp:archive=jposQ.ear</loader-repository>

<module>

  <service>q2mbean-1.0.sar</service>

</module>

</jboss-app>
```

Then the Ear file should have the following files q2mbean-1.0.sar, jpos.jar include the lib dir from jpos to the ear.
Place the deploy folder from jpos in jboss-x.x.x/bin/q2/deploy
Place the log folder and file in jboss-x.x.x/bin/log

Find the sar file here : http://jpos.org/download/q2mbean-1.0.sar